# How to ignore fragment of f-string in python assert

Tags: python, assert, f-string

Is it possible to ignore one fragment of f-string in python assertion, eg.

```
assert results.to_dict() == {
            "comment": f"Retrying in 3600 seconds (1/5)",
        }
```

How to make that any of tries 1-5 was assert as true in this line?
Maybe some regex?

```
assert results.to_dict() == {
            "comment": f"Retrying in 3600 seconds ({some_regex}/5)",
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to write a [regex](https://realpython.com/regex-python/) to solve this? Matching numbers is pretty straightforward.

Comment: An f-string is just a particular syntax for defining a string dynamically. Regardless of how the string is constructed, the *result* is used the same in a string comparison: are corresponding characters in the two strings equal?

Answer (score 2):

I'd just do

```
comment = results.to_dict()["comment"]
assert comment.startswith("Retrying in 3600 seconds")
```

though the effect is slightly different, as you're not checking whether `"comment"` is the only key in the dict anymore. If you need that, you could

```
result = results.to_dict()
comment = result.pop("comment")
# (Pop out more keys)
assert not result  # nothing left unread
assert comment.startswith("Retrying in 3600 seconds")
```

And, then, of course, if you really do want to test whether there really is a retry counter,

```
assert re.match(r"Retrying in 3600 seconds \(\d+/\d+\)", comment)
```

Finally, you could wrap all of this into a helper with a predicate function for each key you want to check:

```
from itertools import partial

def verify_dict_contents(victim, matchers):
    for key, matcher in matchers.items():
        assert key in victim
        assert matcher(victim[key])
    return True

# ...

result = results.to_dict()
assert verify_dict_contents(result, {
  "comment": partial(re.match, r"Retrying in 3600 seconds \(\d+/\d+\)"),
  "number": lambda x: x >= 42
})
```

Comment: Good idea, but I have many keys in this dict. And also, I need to check number of tries as well so I need this "(...)/5" :/

Comment: It needs to be f-string, cos I have there also a few `{}`

Comment: There is no data type called f-string; `return f"foo{4}{2}"` returns a `str`ing `"foo42"`.

Comment: *Why* does it need to be a f-string? People wrote equivalent code for decades without them.